# Beginning Bootstrap for a beginner

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

recently I have tried to use bootstrap to make a site. Although i have tried many different ways to try to put together my website, i feel the need to learn about it more in depth. Does anyone know where i can find a beginner tutorial on how the col-xs-8 things work? That is the main problem that i do not understand. Also how you position different things on your website to be centered is also an area i am not sure how it works. Their are diffenrent tutorials that i have tried already but i do not really understand some of them. Anything would help me out a lot.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all, the bootstrap official documentation is very good IMO: http://getbootstrap.com/

You could also try looking at pluralsight for some Bootstrap tutorials, I am a paying member and I found an absolutely amazing tutorial by Shawn Wildermuth : http://beta.pluralsight.com/courses/bootstrap-3. Shawn Wildermuth is a superb developer and an even better teacher, this is exactly where I went to learn Bootstrap, feel free to watch some of his other videos which are all in depth and excellent tools for learning.

You may be a bit tentative to pay for pluralsight but if you are serious about learning Bootstrap (which is a hands down  awesome framework for web design) That tutorial should help you out immensely and there are many more pluralsight courses which will teach you so much about development. You can even set up a trial account and check out (I think) 2 hours for yourself!

Other then that you just gotta fiddle around and be creative, the best learning is from making mistakes after all.

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is Microsoft Virtual Academy has a free online class called "Building Responsive UI with Bootstrap". The class is a bit lengthy, but it is a really great foundation if you want to invest some time learning Bootstrap. The way that MS presents the class material, it's broken down into different subject areas so you may be able to skip around if you only need to learn about the columns in the grid. Sounds like you are mainly interested in learning about the responsive layout and the grid system. I really enjoyed the MS class, and hope you give it a try!